# Using highcharts to display data from an API

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been checking around all the chart software and ive come to HighCharts.

I want to build a chart thats exactly the same as the one on the following page, http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Im unsure of how to insert my data though, and i was wondering if someone could give me a hand.

The data straight from the source looks like this for example,

```
[[[1473396905000,1.925],[1473402008000,3.8978],[1473402311000,1.3657],[1473402605000,1.3194],[1473402905000,1.4289],[1473403206000,1.5782]]]
```

The first number is a timestamp, the second number is a plot point.

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: is your data going to change? if you look at the graph you mentioned, it has a function which runs every second and changes the data... how do you want your data to flow in the graph? do you want to refresh it every second?

Comment: Hey, The data will update every 5 mins, but essentially be in the same format

Comment: I dont really need the auto updater if its not easy, i just cant get my data to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to display the data then Line graph would be the perfect solution for this. In case you want to use the graph you mentioned and dont want auto update then just remove the whole chart key which has an event and replace the series with the below one.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            var data  = [[1473396905000,1.925],[1473402008000,3.8978],[1473402311000,1.3657],[1473402605000,1.3194],[1473402905000,1.4289],[1473403206000,1.5782]];
            return data;
        }())
    }]
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/muydcyvn/

Comment: That didnt seem to work, im getting an error TypeError: u[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor

Comment: did you look at fiddle? I think the reason could be that you are getting array of array of array where as input to series require array of array.. Can you check that...

Comment: Ahhh yes you are right, i managed to get it working .. Thank you :)